# nginx redirect: /*/ to /*.html (add .html to url)

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

i would like to add ".html" to every document ending on "/", except from the homepage.

i have tried some different ways using rewrite and return 301 with nginx but i didn´t not get it working. attached the last version i did, which is doing /*/.html but the second / should not be there.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri.html;
}
```

**Solution im am looking for:**

root: domain.com should be delivered as www.domain.com

files should be redirected (301) to the *.html version

- domain.com/abc/ to domain.com/abc.html
- domain.com/dir1/abc/ to domain.com/dir1/abc.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use a regular expression to capture the part of the URI *before* the trailing `/`, in order to eliminate it. One solution would be to use a named location with the `try_files` statement.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1.html permanent;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: Was going to ask a similar question but then found this. If anyone is looking for rewriting links that don't have the ".html" part at the end of the url you can use this, just remove `/`  from the rewrite. like so: `rewrite ^(.+)$ $1.html permanent;` This way if someone tries to go to example.com/contact they will get to example.com/html instead of 404.

Comment: @ZN13 appending `.html` can be handled by `try_files` directly, for example: `try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;`. See the link in my answer for details.